# Use jQuery find().show() to show child item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use [jQuery Find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to re-show a hidden word.

When I click on `Div1` words, they will be appended to `Div2` and hidden from `Div1`.

When I click on `Div2` words, they will be removed and reshown in `Div1`.

The only thing that is not working is the word reappearing in `Div1`.

How can I fix this?

I've tried using `find()` to pass in the element that was clicked. Find says it accepts an element, which is what I am passing it to find: `.find( element )`

```
    $('#Div1').on('click', 'li', function () {

        $('#Div2').append('<span>' + $(this).html() + '</span>');

        $(this).hide();
    });

    $('#Div2').on('click', 'span', function (e) {

        console.log($(this)); // [span, context: span]

        $('#Div1').find($(this)).show();

        $(this).remove();

    });
```

In `Div2`, I am console logging the element, which shows:

`console.log($(this)); // [span, context: span]`

Comment: That's like super confusing? If you have `this`, why on earth would you have to find it again ?

Comment: @adeneo typo. Clicking on Div 2 element is supposed to re-show that element in Div 1

Comment: can you provide your html also ?

Comment: Well, that's not going to work, `find` finds elements based on selectors, not what the user clicked in another event listener?

Comment: You want `$('#Div1 li').show()`, but assuming there's more than one LI, you have to keep track of them somehow *(hint : jQuery's `data()`)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Div2`, you can not use `span` selector to find element from first `div`. You can use `:contains()` selector to select that element from `Div1`(Will fail if `Div1` has many `li` with same content)

```js
$('#Div1').on('click', 'li', function() {
  $('#Div2').append('<span>' + $(this).html() + '</span>');
  $(this).hide();
});

$('#Div2').on('click', 'span', function(e) {
  var text = this.innerText;
  $('#Div1 :contains(' + text + ')').show();
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Div1">
  <ul>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Milk</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="Div2"></div>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/6d276d2e/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to adeneo, came up with this:

```
    $('#Div1').on('click', 'li', function () {

        $('#Div2').append('<span data-id="' + $(this).data('id') + '">' + $(this).html() + '</span>');

        $(this).hide();

    });

    $('#Div2').on('click', 'span', function (e) {

        $('#Div1').find('[data-id="' + $(this).data('id') +'"]').show();

        $(this).remove();

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

`$('#Div1').find($(this)).show();`

is looking for the actual clicked element in `#Div1` (which it won't be in, because it's a `#Div2` click), not an element containing the same text as it.

Change it to:

`$('#Div1').find(':contains('+$(this).text()+')').show();`